# MySQL SELECT query with timetable

Tags: mysql, timetable

I have trouble creating Mysql query that will give me a list of id depending on the current time and timetable specified. I have a table like so:

```
ID - int
0f - time (monday from)
0t - time (monday till)
1f - time (tuesday from)
1t - time (tuesday till)
2f - time (wednesday from)
2t - time (wednesday till)
3f - time (thursday from)
3t - time (thursday till)
4f - time (friday from)
4t - time (friday till)
5f - time (saturday from)
5t - time (saturday till)
6f - time (sunday from)
6t - time (sunday till)
```

The problem starts when "till" value is grater than 24 hour and becomes lower then "from" value. 
For example, it is 1am and I need to select all ids that work now and one works from 10am till  2am.

**UPD** That is an example of my table with real data:

```
ID  Name    f0  t0  f1  t1  f2  t2  f3  t3  f4  t4  f5  t5  f6  t6
23  test1   10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    01:00:00    11:00:00    01:00:00    11:00:00    23:00:00
24  test2   12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    02:00:00    12:00:00    02:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00
25  test3   12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    02:00:00    12:00:00    02:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00
27  test4   11:00:00    23:00:00    11:00:00    23:00:00    11:00:00    23:00:00    11:00:00    23:00:00    11:00:00    23:00:00    11:00:00    23:00:00    11:00:00    23:00:00
28  test5   10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00
29  test6   09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00    10:00:00    23:00:00
30  test7   12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00    12:00:00    03:00:00    12:00:00    03:00:00    12:00:00    01:00:00
32  test8   09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    10:00:00    22:00:00    10:00:00    22:00:00
33  test9   11:00:00    22:00:00    11:00:00    22:00:00    11:00:00    22:00:00    11:00:00    22:00:00    11:00:00    22:00:00    11:00:00    22:00:00    11:00:00    22:00:00
34  test10  09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00    09:00:00    22:00:00
35  test11  18:00:00    02:00:00    18:00:00    02:00:00    18:00:00    02:00:00    18:00:00    02:00:00    18:00:00    04:00:00    18:00:00    04:00:00    18:00:00    02:00:00
```

AND I need to write MYSQL query to select ID's that are open now at any time

Comment: so don't limit your time values from 0->23. mysql time type can go +/- 839 hours. treat hour 25 as "tomorrow", hour -1 as "yesterday".

Comment: Okay, but I still don't understand how to create a query that would count for this? @MarcB

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you want here? And also fill in the whole table. What are your "arguments", and what is the exact list of IDs that you would want returned in this example?

Comment: Please don't type your question title in ALL CAPS. Typing in ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING here, just like everywhere else on the internet. SHOUTING will not get you help any more quickly, it makes your title more difficult to read, and it's really rude and annoying when someone asking for **free help** to solve **their problem** feels the need to SHOUT to get more attention. Please be courteous and polite, and wait your turn like everyone else. If someone can help you, they will, but it won't make them do it more quickly when you shout at them.

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to be rude or to shout out. @KenWhite

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking for here. So I will offer a couple of observations.

First, given any `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, or `DATETIME` value, for example a column with the name `datestamp`, this formula will give you precisely midnight of the Monday of that week. (There's a little bit of magic in this formula, because MySQL's DAY 0 happens to be a Sunday.)

```
 FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -2, 7))
```

Then, you can add an arbitrary number of hours to that. So, for example, if you have an eight-hour work shift that begins at 23:00 on Wednesday, it begins 71 (24 + 24 + 23) hours after the beginning of the present week. So it begins at

```
 FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -2, 7)) 
          + INTERVAL 71 HOUR
```

The end of that shift in the present week, eight hours later, is at this time.

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -2, 7))
          + INTERVAL 71 HOUR
          + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

So, maybe (**???**) you want to represent your "Thursday till" sorts of items as hours after the beginning of the week.

This is just an idea for a way to represent recurring weekly events in your dbms, while still getting the advantages of MySQL's date arithmetic.